# API calls to backend from Salesforce flow

Tags: rest-api, visual-workflow, flow

I'm trying to figure out how to create RESTful API calls to my backend from inside the Salesforce flow - for example i want to retrieve a field from my backend and then make a decision upon that field. Anyone know if it's possible and how to do it? Thanks, Udi

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [good resource for learning about Invocable Actions,](https://unofficialsf.com/flow-actions/) which enable what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You will need to write an [Apex plugin](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_process_plugin_using.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fapex_process_plugin_using.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) to do a [callout](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_callouts_http.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fapex_callouts_http.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp), and drop that into the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its possible. There are multiple options available. To connect your flow to an external database, use platform events, external objects, Lightning components, Enhanced External Services, or Apex.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_build_data_integrate.htm&type=5